# Looking for an SBC board for streaming H.264 videos

Tags: sbc

I connected a seagate 2TB to a beaglebone black for a media server setup. On my phone I installed VLC player, the setup works fine and it plays very well. Until I play H.264 videos, initially it works fine but it continuously trying to buffer, like you are on a slow internet watching YouTube. So now I am thinking of two options:

1. An SBC powerful enough to stream H.264 videos on the local network, with gigabit Ethernet, but less than 150$ (The less the better).
2. I have an extra beaglebone green so I thought of setting up a "cluster" from these two (Would it work?)

What do you think?

Comment: Dear @ArtOfCode, I clearly explained my problem with "initially it works fine but it continuously trying to buffer, like you are on a slow internet watching YouTube". That is the problem I am facing with the beaglebone black.